# install cloud9 on beaglebone debian

Tags: git, build

im trying to install cloud9 under debian 8 on a beaglebone.
Like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/rcn-ee/bb.org-cloud9-core.git
cd bb.org-cloud9-core/
./build.sh
```

But i get this error and don't know how to fix that:

```
From https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.language
 * [new branch]      c9         -> origin/c9
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: ambiguous argument 'c2740d0254': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you seen your C9 Ide state (in some cases C9 is already embedded in debian dist.)? Try this 3 following commands:

```
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable bonescript.socket
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable cloud9.socket
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable bonescript-autorun.service
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question has been asked, but you can now install the Cloud 9 IDE using:

```sh
sudo apt install c9-core-installer
```

Once installed you can navigate to http://beaglebone:3000/, or if that does not work use http://[IP_of_your_BeagleBone]:3000/.  It will take a while for Cloud9 IDE to load.